# Reinstall Windows 8 on an existing bootcamp installation

Tags: macbook-pro, boot-camp, windows-8, windows-installation

I already have a functioning bootcamp installation of Windows 8 on my MacBook Pro.

I'd like to re-install Windows 8 (newer version) to the same bootcamp partition-- can I simply boot from the Win 8 CD/DVD and reinstall over the existing partition, or do I need to go through the bootcamp wizard in Mac OSX and start the whole process over?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to install Windows 8 RTM over the Windows 8 release preview bootcamp installation by simply downloading the ISO, mounting it, and opening Setup.exe in Windows.

After that, I booted back into OSX and used the Boot Camp Assistant to download the necessary drivers to a USB flashdrive. (I would have used Windows update, but the WIFI drivers were not working).

Then installed Bootcamp on Win 8 and everything is good.

Note:

I tried booting from a USB drive based on the ISO, but wasn't able to boot from it. (I held down the option key while restarting, but the USB device didn't show up).

I also tried booting from a burned copy of the ISO, but wasn't able to boot from that either.